# Speak failed, not bound to TTS Engine (on a Service)

Tags: android, text-to-speech

So I have a Service that is able to speak.
I also have an Activity that enables/disables the Service from speaking.

The thing is, when I Start the Service after destroying it the TTS disconnects from the Engine, how do I reconnect it?

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {

    if (tts == null) {
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
            }
    }
```

and the onInit

```
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {

    this.status = status;
    if (this.status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

        if (tts == null) {
            tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
            tts.setSpeechRate(0.8f);
        }
        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installIntent);
        }
    }

}
```

onDestroy

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
        Log.d("TAG", "TTS Destroyed");
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: remove that `if` condition from `onStart()` and directly initialize it.

Comment: I removed it and it's not it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding some logging into your code to see where it is failing.

Firstly, try putting `tts = null;` after `tts.shutdown();` in `onDestroy()`

If that doesn't work, check the status `onInit`. At the moment your code handles success, but you appear to do nothing if you get a fail message message.

Put logging in the `OnStart` and `OnInit` to check you are correctly calling them - it may be an error somewhere in your code that you are not detailing above.